# Can we POST values coming from url

Tags: php

I want to POST values coming from a url .

My url is `xxx.com/aa.php?name=RAM`

On aa.php page I have written like this

`<?php $NAME=$_POST["name"]; ?>`

but its value is getting  null .

but when using GET Method its values is getting as 'RAM'.

How can I retrieve values using POST from a url ? or is it not possible?

Comment: You should use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: What. `$_GET` is for URL, `$_POST` is for input posted with a form. Is your question, "How can hide the URL, so that I can still get name=RAM, but it not showing up in the URL?"

Comment: You have to first understand GET and POST as it is evident you are missing the basics\

Comment: use the curl to post the data without using form.

Comment: No you need to use $_GET for that purpose. It is exactly why we have $_GET and $_POST.

Comment: $_POST and $_GET both are different terms and different functionality . To get the data from the url with a query string you have to use the $_GET method. $_POST is only for the data passed through the Form submission with post method .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the parameter is in the URL it is a `GET` parameter.
You can not fetch a `GET` parameter from the `$_POST` array, but the `$_GET` array.
You can also use the `$_REQUEST` Array to get both `POST` and `GET` variables.

In your case, the `GET` variable with the key `name` is `RAM`, as it should be.

---

*edit:*
Worth to mention is that the `$_REQUEST` array pretty much is a concatenation of `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`, so it might behave unexpected if any of the others (than the one you are after) are using the same key names.
I would recommend using the type you are actually wanting, in this case, the `$_GET` list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

```
<?php $NAME=$_GET["name"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure about `$_GET` & `$_POST` method then you can try `$_REQUEST` also.

```
$NAME=$_GET["name"];  //work in get method

$NAME=$_POST["name"]; //work in post method

$NAME=$_REQUEST["name"]; //work in both method
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to pass the data with hidden method is either you should use curl or using form submission with post method like

```
<form name="" action="aa.php" method="post">
<input typ="hidden" name="name" value="RAM">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

then you can get this as 

$_POST['name'] 
on aa.php page
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you are not sure about your method i.e. $_GET or $_POST.you should use $_REQUEST.
>   $NAME=$_REQUEST["name"];

for more information:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm